# Watermarking on PDF files using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, watermark

I am developing a website which needs to create PDF files dynamically. All those things completed and I am using PHP. Now there is one more facility needed that after the creation of PDF file, watermark should be added to every page ( on center position ) . Watermark image will be uploaded by the user. Please help me with sample codes.

Thank You,
Syam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd check out this PHP Class on Github by binarystash. It seems to do what you are asking for. 
https://github.com/binarystash/PDFWatermarker

Hopefully this helps.