# How do I add a watermark to a PDF using PHP and without removing dynamic content?

Tags: php, pdf

Recently I've been assigned to a project that requires adding a watermark to every page of a PDF file. However, while the PDF is always the same, the watermark for the PDF has to be custom-made to contain the email of any user who downloads it.

After some digging, I found the FPDF and [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) libraries for PHP. These libraries allow me to easily add custom watermarks to my PDF files, but by design they cause the resulting PDFs to lack Dynamic Content. The original PDF is quite large, so it requires internal links for easy navigation. Because PDFs edited with FPDI lacks dynamic content, those internal links are removed in the watermarked version of the PDF.

After some more searching, I've found an existing [workaround](https://gist.github.com/andreyvit/2020422) for this problem using an extension of the FPDI library. However, that solution requires a vastly outdated version of FPDI that doesn't seem to function properly on my site.

All that said, my question is this: 
Barring the above solution, are there any existing PHP libraries that allow me to add custom watermarks to a pdf file without removing the original PDF file's internal links? I'm willing to pay for a license if I have to, but was hoping for a solution priced, at the very least, under $50.

Comment: surely you want the solution priced at the very *most* under $50? Unless you just want to chuck away money? `:-D`

Comment: I think this link will help you alot
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115180/watermarking-on-pdf-files-using-php

Comment: @ZearaeZ The PDF Watermarker linked in the answer to that question specifically states it's using FPDF and FPDI. Again, that means it isn't going to work for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I've came up with:

Editing a pdf with php a cost effective manner isn't viable. If you're working with a single pdf, use an online service to convert it into an HTML file (there are many), then use php to edit in a watermark for that file document. Once that's done, use a service like [Prince HTML](http://www.princexml.com/) to convert that HTML file back into a newly watermarked pdf to download.

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating your PDF with your own HTML template than you can easily add a Image Div and make this opacity 0.1 it will place your image like a watermark. And there is also a good project on github. You can look at this https://github.com/binarystash/pdf-watermarker

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using an HTML template; I only have a pdf file to work with. I really wish I wasn't! That also means PDF-Watermaker won't work; it uses FPDF and FPDI which strips dynamic content from my pdf by design.